# Array of Dictionaries or multiple arrays , which is best?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, architecture, dictionary, oop

I came across a requirement to parse xml or json and have to list them in table.

I have no problem in achieving this but i would like to optimize the code to use less memory resources.

The question is that is it best to have multiple arrays or is it better to have a single array whose contents are dictionaries.

please have a look at following example in which 3 names are saved in 2 ways

**Way 1**

```
NSArray* names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"rama krishna",@"firstname",
                   @"chunduri",@"surname",
                   nil],
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"rama krishna",@"firstname",
                   @"gutta",@"surname",
                   nil],
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"selvakumar",@"firstname",
                   @"k",@"surname",
                   nil],
                  nil];
```

**Way 2**

```
NSArray *firstnames=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Rama Krishna",@"Rama Krishna",@"selvakumar",nil];
NSArray *surnames=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"chunduri",@"gutta",@"k",nil];
```

So, which one of these 2 ways can be prefered for optimized memory consumption.

Answer (score 10):

You have just encountered an excellent place to use object-oriented programming.

You dictionaries which map for example, "firstname" to "rama krishna" and "surname" to "gutta", should really be grouped into a class with an `NSString*` instance variable for surname and firstname.

E.g.:

```
@interface Person : NSObject {
    NSString *firstname;
    NSString *surname;
}

@end
```

Then you will just have an array of `Person` objects. Much easier to use, and the "correct" way to do things, in most cases. Anyone who touches your code will thank you.

Comment: Your solution is nice, i mentioned firstname,surname for an example.

Comment: Great answer. Programming in iOS always makes me too focused on using Cocoa Touch's frameworks that I get too lost in using NSArrays and NSDictionaries and forget to use proper object oriented programming.

Comment: For modern Objective-C, you'll want to use properties instead of ivars  as given in the code examples!

Answer (score 0):

The better choice would be adding **dictionary** in an **array**. i.e one array and multiple dictionaries. I used this in my lastest application :

```
// In a loop
NSMutableDictionary *dictError=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:maxCount,kID,kUsers,kEntity,[Utils convertDateInString:[NSDate date]],kDate,kTrue,kStatus,kEnter,kDescription, nil];
[arrError addObject:dictError];
```

In this way you can add dictionary as array objects.And to get indvisual disctionary object:

```
NSMutableDictionary *nameDictionary = [arrError objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *strEntityName = [nameDictionary objectForKey:@"KeyName"];
```

Comment: I really don't think dictionaries are the best way to do things. Why don't you just create an object to store the data?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.so way 2 will reduce memory consumption.

Comment: @Chris: Very well said. What I am suggesting is to go for single array and multiple dictionary instead of vice verse for which Rama has asked for.

Comment: @Chris: Now the rest API in our server is changed resulting to have additional fields sex,occupation,relationship status etc in the profile. 

Since i used array of dictionaries and parsed all json into a tableview those new fields are also displayed well without modifying anything on code. 
If we have own object classes then definitely app modifies to store those new fields in new ivars.

So conclusion is when we have a finite amount of attribs to be stored we can go for object oriented or we have to stick to dictionaries when need to store infinite attribs.